# Running AIR Mobile AS3 App on mobile?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I use flash developer and create AIR Mobile AS3 App and I wonder how can I change an app run time from desktop to my mobile device?

Thanks

Comment: A bit of googling seems to reveal an answer... also generally SO is reserved for questions that include code and/or show prior research. http://www.photonstorm.com/archives/2431/creation-of-a-mobile-app-without-the-flash-ide-for-all-flashdevelop-lovers I didn't down-vote or vote to close, as you can edit the question if you encounter issues and can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In flash builder, you have to set the Run/debug configuration, what looks like below:
[image]

you have to select the platform (Android, BBRY, etc), and "On device". If you have Android device for example, make sure its connected, and in development mode. It should work,but you'll find lots of help.